# Pattern matching in C# to remove series in parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I am using `RegularExpressions.Regex` to try and match the following text:

```
(X12345 5/10/2012 21:32) - (X12345 5/14/2012 21:32) - summary text 123
```

I would like to remove any series of values in parenthesis at the beginning of the string (including any hyphens that exist).  Once text is encountered that is not in parenthesis then I'd like to stop the match and return only what was not matched.

For example, I would like to see only "summary text 123" returned from the regex operation.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you give an example of what you would like the output of such a match to be from the example input you specified?

Comment: Thanks.  I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this pattern:

```
^\s*(\([^)]*\)[\s-]*)+[\s-]*
```

with nothing.

Comment: Works perfect, and thanks much for adding in the example code.  Very well done!